# Dynamic diff of one file

Tags: bash, diff

I am trying to diff one file over time using process substitution in bash.

```
diff <(cat /path/to/file | sort; sleep 20) <(cat /path/to/file)
```

I also tried:

```
diff <(cat /path/to/file | sort && sleep 20) <(cat /path/to/file)
```

The diffs seem to always match as though it is sleeping first and then cat'ing the files. The process substitution works otherwise if using two different files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Use [watch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) to run your command at an interval.

```
watch -n 20 'bash -c "diff <(cat /path/to/file | sort) <(cat /path/to/file)"'
```

That particular command could be written more simply like this.

```
watch -n 20 'bash -c "diff <(sort /path/to/file) /path/to/file"'
```

*Update:*

Alternatively, maybe because watch doesn't show all the output, you could put your command in a while loop.

```
while true; do diff <(sort /path/to/file) /path/to/file; sleep 20; done
```